# Where should i need to configure spark cores usage

Tags: snappydata

I configured -spark.executor.cores=16 in leads but when i starts snappy i am getting

WARNING: daemonize() not available in base implementation snappydata

and also i tried with

export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=16

but it is not reflected in cores usage, it uses all cores available in my server

Comment: How many cores do you have available? How many workers started, when you specify 'SPARK_WORKER_CORES=16'?

Comment: I have 40 core server.when i look at cpu usage it reaches 4000